# Racket language questions tagging: tags "plt-scheme" and "racket"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

We maybe still need [plt-scheme](/questions/tagged/plt-scheme), but I'm asking if we need that tag on the new questions. E. g. it would be ok for [Abstracting functions / avoiding repetition in functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4611731/298282) to have [racket](/questions/tagged/racket) (or maybe better [racket-language](/questions/tagged/racket-language)?) and optionally [scheme](/questions/tagged/scheme), because [plt-scheme](/questions/tagged/plt-scheme) refers to the language from which Racket has grown – [With the release of version 5.0, PLT Scheme was renamed to Racket](http://racket-lang.org/new-name.html).

**UPDATE**: We now have the tags synonyms "plt-scheme" and "drscheme". Thank you, thank you, people, thank you. I'm glad you helped us with votes. Thank you very much. :-)

Comment: I remember there was a discussion about this before, but a whole bunch of retag requests got deleted... I really wish we could search deleted questions. Let me see if I can find it by date.

Comment: Well, I'm sure it's in there somewhere, but it's eluding me.

Comment: @Jon Seigel :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't actually need [plt-scheme](/questions/tagged/plt-scheme) anymore, because Racket is backward compatible with PLT Scheme, and most users have already updated their environments.

We don't need [plt-scheme](/questions/tagged/plt-scheme), we are happy with [racket](/questions/tagged/racket).

Comment: I asked at some point for all `plt-scheme` tags to be replaced by `racket`, and since there was no reply to that, I just went ahead and manually did the replacement on all questions that I found.  There is no need for `plt-scheme`, even for questions that ask about past versions, since it's all known as "Racket" now -- and "PLT Scheme" should at best be considered as a name that was used for Racket in the past.

Comment: @Eli: Thanks for your reply. I suggested the tag-synonym [plt-scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/racket/synonyms). If you think this is reasonable idea, and you're able to note the people about the tag and the need for votes, then notify them.

Comment: @Eli: I've also created a tag synonym for "drscheme", as I saw a question, tagged "drscheme" a couple of weeks ago, which AFAIR didn't have the tag "scheme".

Comment: @Yasir: I'm not sure how the synonym system works -- in general, what you said in this answer is what should happen: uses of `plt-scheme` and `drscheme` should be considered as old tags that should now be replaced with `racket`.  If that's what the synonyms that you created lead to then that's perfect.  Is there anything else that I should do?

Comment: @Eli: Please, read [Create Tag Synonyms](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms). And all you should do is just [vote for the tag synonyms](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/racket/synonyms), I suggested, and make others know about the suggestions, so that they head there and vote :-)

Comment: Seems like it'll be difficult to find people who can actually do this...

Comment: @Eli: 2 individuals already did. 2 more votes needed. I used Freenode ;-)

Comment: Yasir: Yeah, I'm one of the two, and we already asked on freenode which resulted in a second...  There's a few racket people who are semi-active on SO, but they don't have enough points for upvoting.

Comment: @Eli: I have an idea. I'm going to ask answerers at SO to vote. Have just made one such request here "[Including and external file in Racket](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4809433/298282)". ;->

Comment: Yasir: Heh -- the two people that I've asked are Sam and Jon, neither have enough points...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we still need [plt-scheme](/questions/tagged/plt-scheme), because users that haven't yet updated to Racket want their questions be distinguished from Racket, and they don't tag their questions [plt-scheme](/questions/tagged/plt-scheme) and [racket](/questions/tagged/racket) together simultaneously, because nine times of ten it's meaningless (*they often do*).

We need [plt-scheme](/questions/tagged/plt-scheme).